# how to query on PostgreSQL view using Java / Vaadin?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, vaadin

I am trying to fetch data from a [view in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) using Java and [Vaadin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin). I get an error saying that there is no [primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key). But Postgres does not support having a primary key on a view.

Ho do I do that query?

Comment: Hi, can anyone help here?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Vaadin view has no relevance to Postgre or any other database. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: How do you access your database? With the sqlcontainer, jpa or.....

Comment: @user3551612: it's either Postgres or PostgreSQL but never Postgre

Answer (score 2):

you can make key to primary key in postgres like this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT table_name_pkey PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2);
```

**EDIT**
Use this link for query on view: [queries for postgresql view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/rules-views.html)

Comment: The question is related to views; not tables. Can you suggest how to query on views?